# custom datepicker can't get text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, datepicker

Hi I have a custom datepicker but my problem is it won't changed when I hit backspace and erase the date in text box. It still returns the prev value. But when I change it to a valid date it works fine. What shall I do with this to detect that there is an empty text so I can validate it as required field and can't be blank. The textbox in the datepicker is masked ones.

I tired putting another property as text but it still passes the prev. date value. I tried getting the dtValue instead and is passing "__ /**_ /__**" which affected my binding. Any suggestions please? thanks.

```
public partial class MaskedDatePicker : UserControl
{
    public MaskedDatePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void datePicker1_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dtValue.Focus();
    }

    private void datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtPicker.SelectedDate.HasValue)
        {
            dtValue.Text = dtPicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            dtValue.EnteredDate = dtPicker.SelectedDate.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            dtValue.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            dtValue.EnteredDate = DateTime.Today;
        }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty DateValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DateValue", typeof(DateTime), typeof(MaskedDatePicker));

    public DateTime? DateValue
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(DateValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DateValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private void dtPicker_CalendarOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dtValue.Text, out dt))
        {
            dtValue.EnteredDate = dt;
            dtPicker.SelectedDate = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            dtPicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            dtValue.EnteredDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime result;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(dtValue.Text, out result))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public new void Focus()
    {
        dtValue.Focus();
    }

    private void dtPicker_CalendarClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dtValue.Focus();
    }
}
```

here is the xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:DateConverter x:Key="DateConverter" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..\ResourceDictionary\ResourceWPF.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Border BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="#FF7F9DB9" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <commonWPF:MaskedTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,2" Style="{StaticResource MaskedDateStyle}"
                            Mask="00/00/0000" x:Name="dtValue" BorderThickness="1" 
                            Text="{Binding ElementName=usrMaskedDatePicker, Path=DateValue, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
                            Width="70" Height="Auto"/>
        <my:DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Height="Auto" x:Name="dtPicker"
                       Width="26" BorderThickness="0" PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="datePicker1_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" 
                       SelectedDateChanged="datePicker1_SelectedDateChanged" 
                       SelectedDate="{Binding ElementName=usrMaskedDatePicker, Path=DateValue}" CalendarOpened="dtPicker_CalendarOpened" IsTabStop="False" IsDropDownOpen="False" 
                       CalendarClosed="dtPicker_CalendarClosed"
                       KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" >
        </my:DatePicker>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: What language? C++ VC++ C# ??

Answer (score 0):

Some crucial code is still missing - where is the code for the commonWPF:maskedTextBox, where is the code for my:DatePicker?

Inorder to to fix your problem, you must step through your code with the debugger and look what is happening when you are deleting your text.

Basically, I think that if you delete your text you are not (re)setting the property that holds your Date value (perhaps because the entered date is not valid / is empty, you only set if it is valid / fully entered).
Because you don't set the value to the now deleted value (an empty value), you still get the previous value stored in the Date value property.